# Redirect to URL if input exists in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to redirect a user to an existing URL (stored in a MySQL database) if the value they input already exists in the database. I've got *most* of it working, but I've run into some issues.

I'm using AJAX to check the database. It sends the input value to another PHP file & checks the database to see if it already exists.

```
if($row) {
    echo ".$row["itemNum"].";
} else {

}
```

It's within the AJAX code that I'm having issues, in particular this:

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response == <?php ".$row["itemNum"]." ?>) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/" <?php echo "+"; if (".$row["itemNum"].") { echo ".$row["itemNum"]." } else {""}
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

`$row["itemNum"]` doesn't always exist, so it's in a conditional statement to prevent a syntax error.

The above doesn't work regardless of how I do it.

I have a feeling the main issue is with the `if (response == <?php ".$row["itemNum"]." ?>)` line?

Comment: try to remove your `echo "+";` line like : `window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/ <?php if ($row["itemNum"]) { echo $row["itemNum"]; };`

Comment: You might also want to change `if (response == <?php ".$row["itemNum"]." ?>)` to `if (response == '<?php ".$row["itemNum"]." ?>')`, i.e. add apostrophes around the echoed value.

Comment: You can't mixing php (server side) and js (client side) like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this code:-

```
if($row) {
    echo $row["itemNum"]; // check the change here
} else {

}
```

You have to do like this:-

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response !== '') { // if response have some value
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/"+response;
    } else {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you suspected you have problem with following line.

```
if (response == <?php ".$row["itemNum"]." ?>) {
```

The Problem is your use of (") and (.) characters

Following syntax will give you what you want.

```
if (response == <?=$row["itemNum"]?>) {
```